# Is CROSSJOIN between a hierarchy and a dimension attribute possible?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am currently displaying the descendants of the agent branch hierarchy up to the agent name level using the MDX:

```
UNION (
{DESCENDANTS ([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Retail],5,SELF_AND_BEFORE) }
,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Digital],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}        
,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Telesales],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}  
,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Head Office],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)} 
)
```

However, I would like to display the `AgentEmployeeNumber` alongside the name of the agent. `AgentEmployeeNumber` is not part of the `AgentBranch Hierarchy` though and I can't seem to find a way of cross-joining the two together, is this possible at all? I have supplied a snip of the structure of the agent dimension below:

[image: Agent Dimension]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross join (short form of that is `*`) for (I assume) the rows like this:

```
SELECT
    {} // add whatever you want, I assume you have measures here
    ON COLUMNS,
    UNION (
        {DESCENDANTS ([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Retail],5,SELF_AND_BEFORE) }
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Digital],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}        
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Telesales],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}  
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Head Office],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)} 
    )
    *
    [Agent].[Agent Employee Number].[Agent Employee Number].Members
ON ROWS
FROM [Your Cube]
```

The downside is that for `Agent Branch Hierarchy` members not on single agent level, you will get many numbers. One way around this would be a calculated measure which you would put on the columns:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Employee Number] AS
     IIf(
         (EXISTING [Agent].[Agent Employee Number].[Agent Employee Number].Members).Count = 1,
         (EXISTING [Agent].[Agent Employee Number].[Agent Employee Number].Members).Item(0).Item(0).Name,
         NULL
     )
SELECT
    Measures.[Employee Number] // add whatever you want, I assume you have measures here
    ON COLUMNS,
    UNION (
        {DESCENDANTS ([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Retail],5,SELF_AND_BEFORE) }
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Digital],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}        
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Telesales],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)}  
        ,{DESCENDANTS([Agent].[Agent Branch Hierarchy].[Agent Business Division].&[Head Office],5, SELF_AND_BEFORE)} 
    )
ON ROWS
FROM [Your Cube]
```

The member definition statesmore or less: "If the set of employee numbers for the current `Agent Branch Hierarchy` member has exactly one element, then take the first (and only) element's name as the measure value. Note that calculated measures can return strings, and need not necessarily be numeric.